# Object is not defined in the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to send information to another page, but i'm getting this error.

angular.min.js:107 ReferenceError: layoutTeste is not defined

This is my code.

```
 vm.editar = function () { 
            $state.go("importacaoPreFaturaValidar", {
            layoutTeste: vm.layouteste
         });
         }
```

the vm.layouteste has values, but the layoutTeste says is not defined.

What did i miss, in the scope i put.

```
vm.layoutTeste = [];
```

Comment: is this angular 1.x??

Comment: Typo: layouteste !=== layoutTeste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter within quotes

```
$state.go("importacaoPreFaturaValidar", {
    'layoutTeste': vm.layouteste
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this and also i didnt get my values in the other page, i put     vm.carregarLayoutTeste = $stateParams.layoutTeste,

Comment: What difference does this make?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error. Try:

```
$state.go("importacaoPreFaturaValidar", {
        layoutTeste: vm.layouteste
     }).bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **arrow function** instead. This way you will retain the original scope, which is now considered as undefined.

```
vm.editar = () => { 
            $state.go("importacaoPreFaturaValidar", {
            layoutTeste: vm.layouteste
         });
         }
```